# Undefined http response from requests between containers with docker compose

Tags: http, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to set up a CI testing environment with docker compose for an API. I have two docker files, one for the API to run and the other for my tests. Both run and execute properly but when trying to access the url for the API from the testing container I am unable to do an http request getting undefined as a response.

They are connected using a default bridge connection. The API is being port forwarded 80:80 and I am able to grab the data on my localhost and in the bash for the API container. I have tried multiple different versions of what to use for testing the API from the test container:

```
api-internal/login
api-internal:80/login
ci_api-internal_1/login
ci_api-internal_1:80/login
172.18.0.2/login
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
    version: '2'

services:
  api-internal:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=local
  ci:
    build: ./integration-test
    volumes_from:
      - api-internal
```

Network:

```
"Scope": "local",
"Driver": "bridge",
"EnableIPv6": false,
"IPAM": {
    "Driver": "default",
    "Options": null,
    "Config": [
        {
            "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
            "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
        }
    ]
},
"Internal": false,
"Containers": {
    "9249966d1b111b61959c3e1afdbb3b7d86267469e51aa372c614448fecee2532": {
        "Name": "ci_ci_1",
        "EndpointID": "a3d1edc1759fddc9a887ae68b3c9504f653ce427c3e2f8fb818a8c9dd7701d25",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
        "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    },
    "c950d69ce73b46e1d5cabe6811a27675f497a01518c03595d5b892756ba3066c": {
        "Name": "ci_api-internal_1",
        "EndpointID": "b8f3fad279eeeaeac50a5639bec2468272a9dc3e0635f60faee7accb9b908c4c",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
        "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Never use images for adding code content, edit your post and use the code indentation button (looks something like this `{ }`) for adding the source code for `docker-compose.yml` and the network config.